# Redirect to another page after window.open

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I want after click on a button a file will generate and open in new window and user redirect from parent page to another page.

```
     string script = "<script>window.open('" FilePath "')</script>";
                    Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
                    if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("pdf"))
                    {
                        page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "pdf", script);

                    }
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

I write above code to open the garaged file new window and then redirect.

But if the redirection code is there the window.open is not working .
without redirection window.open working fine.

can any one tell me whats going wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the redirection after the html content is loaded on the client. So in this case you have to redirect with javascript on the client.

```
string script = "<script>window.open('" FilePath "'); window.location.href = '/Login.aspx';</script>";
```